# Command Line Previous for Gnome Gui

Tags: gnome

I'm pretty new to Linux, but trying to learn. Ive installed Ubuntu 18 as a VM and playing around.

I was wondering, is there a plugin/application/scheme (not sure of proper term) that allows you to preview what linux is doing in the shell when you do things in the GUI?

For those of you familiar with Windows Server environments, im looking for something like the "Preview powershell command" button that is in the bottom of the gui windows.

I feel this would help me a ton on learning commands and seeing what is actually happening in the shell.

For example when i install a program using the 'ubuntu software' repository, and click to install 'terminator' is there something that someone has created that will let me see "sudo apt install terminator" ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None come to mind that are similar to Windows' "Preview powershell command". Then again, linux != windows and you'd be better served to not think of it in that sense.

My advice would be if you want to learn linux, ditch the gui entirely and if you don't know, then google it. If after searching and really doing your homework then ask. No whether or not you put it on bare metal or a vm is up to you. Ultimatley I see the program you are looking for as a crutch that will be hard to ditch in the future.